# swagger api can't send array as response

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, swagger

I am learnin Node js, and I have a node swagger api. I'm trying to retrieve game statistics based on 2 input teams. I query mongodb with this function:

```
    function getTeamVsTeamRecord(req, res) {
      var team1 = req.swagger.params.team1.value;
      var team2 = req.swagger.params.team2.value;
      stats.find({
        game: /2016/,
        $or:[
          {'data.home.abbr': team1, 'data.away.abbr': team2},
          {'data.away.abbr': team1, 'data.home.abbr': team2}
        ]}).toArray(function(err, results){
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({error: 'error.code', message: 'An error happened in the server !'})
        }
        if (typeof results !== 'undefined' && results.length > 0) {
          console.log("search returned: " + results.length + " results");
          console.log(results);
          res.json(results);
        }
        else {
          res.status(500).json({error: 'error 1', message: 'search returned nothing'})
        }
      });
    }
```

the output of the results object looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 59ea18c21fff646c417b078c,
    game: '2016100201',
    data: 
     { home: [Object],
       away: [Object],
       drives: [Object],
       scrsummary: [Object],
       weather: null,
       media: null,
       yl: '',
       qtr: 'Final',
       note: null,
       down: 0,
       togo: 0,
       redzone: true,
       clock: '00:34',
       posteam: 'ATL',
       stadium: null },
    nextupdate: 246 },
  { _id: 59ea18c61fff646c417b0bac,
    game: '2016122401',
    data: 
     { home: [Object],
       away: [Object],
       drives: [Object],
       scrsummary: [Object],
       weather: null,
       media: null,
       yl: '',
       qtr: 'Final',
       note: null,
       down: 0,
       togo: 0,
       redzone: true,
       clock: '00:44',
       posteam: 'CAR',
       stadium: null },
    nextupdate: 318 } ]
```

As you can see i retrieve 2 sets of game statistics in this query. My issue is it fails schema validation as swagger expects json syntax. I tried JSON.stringify and this lead to bad array errors. I can successfully send

```
res.json = results[0].data
```

as a response, but this only works when there is 1 item in the array. Is there any way to send the whole array as a json response?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an object "o" and adding the results from the array to this object as follows:

```
function getTeamVsTeamRecord(req, res) {
  var team1 = req.swagger.params.team1.value;
  var team2 = req.swagger.params.team2.value;
  var year = req.swagger.params.year.value;
  var o = {};
  stats.find({
    game: {$regex: ".*" + year + ".*"},
    $or:[
      {'data.home.abbr': team1, 'data.away.abbr': team2},
      {'data.away.abbr': team1, 'data.home.abbr': team2}
    ]}).toArray(function(err, results){
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({error: 'error.code', message: 'An error happened in the server !'})
    }
    if (typeof results !== 'undefined' && results.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var game = "res" + i;
        o[game] = results[i];
      }
      res.json(o);
    }
    else {
      res.status(500).json({error: 'error 1', message: 'search returned nothing'})
    }
  });
}
```